# Rejoin Favorite Chatrooms

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

This script adds a link to rejoin favorite chatrooms, even if you're in multiple ones already:

[image]

### About

When you're in only one chatroom on a server, there's an orange button which you can use to quickly join all your favorite chatrooms:

[image]

However, that button disappears if you're in two or more rooms. This script brings back that functionality.

#### Download

The script can be installed via [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/rejoin-favorite-chatrooms/rejoin-favorite-chatrooms.user.js); source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/rejoin-favorite-chatrooms/rejoin-favorite-chatrooms.user.js).

#### Platform

Tested with Violentmonkey in Firefox on macOS, but it's likely to work on all browsers and platforms. (Please let me know if it doesn't!)

### Contact

Post a comment or answer here, or create an issue/pull request on GitHub.